# Next term in the given series

Tags: number-theory, puzzle, pattern-recognition

What will be next term of given series:

$$​50, 30, 40, 75, 170, ?$$

I am not able to find the pattern in the series. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Could be anything you wish.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790642/general-formula-for-the-1-5-19-65-211-sequence

Comment: See question 5 here: http://emahendras.org/downlods/Digi-Page-22-06-2016-Reasoning-English.pdf Apparently the answer is 450.

Comment: @jim I am glad to see that someone agrees with me that "the guessing of the next term from a finite number of samples" is an unfair game .

Comment: @jim I believe pattern recognition is *on topic* on MSE, if there exists a tag for it. So I hardly think this is a valid response. Of course the OP could try to provide more context.

Comment: @smcc holy cow, those are all really difficult

Comment: Not so difficult when the answer is given with the questions

Comment: Well yeah, but even with the answers I have no idea what the reasoning is

Comment: For example. problem $2$ the sequence is $1\times11, 2\times 11, 4\times 11, 7\times 11,11\times 11$. OEIS can find $170$ sequences starting with $1,2,4,7,11,$ and only $54$ of these predict the next term "correctly"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x_1=50$$
$$x_{n+1}=n\left(\frac{x_n}{2}+5\right)$$

[My python code to verify it.](http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user41_v5mIfnPzs0tI3h8.py)