# Please help to find the rule used to generate the sequence of integers.

Tags: abstract-algebra, sequences-and-series, prime-numbers

Given the sequence of integer numbers. Needed to find rule which was used to produce these numbers.

The sequence is :

**0,  0,  1,  2,  5,  6,  9,  10,  13,  18,  19,  24,  27,  28,  31,  36.**

Here are first **16** members of the sequence. It can be infinitely extended if necessary.

Comment: The OEIS finds [A065890](https://oeis.org/A065890).

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1790666/44121

Comment: Can you explain where you found this sequence? (I would remove my vote to close...)

Comment: This sequence is the number of composite numbers which are less than next prime integer. For instance if we consider the sequence of primes:
2, 3, 5, 7, 11, ... than the number of composite numbers which precede them will be: 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, etc.

Comment: Since the definition involves prime numbers, a simple, straightforward formula is unlikely. It's important to note, though, that if you didn't know the definition, many possible alternate definitions are possible. For instance, you can easily come up with a sequence of the first $n$ primes followed by a composite number, and it has a mathematical formula. e.g., http://oeis.org/A059999

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented before, there are infinite solutions. We only need to consider the family of Lagrange interpolation polynomials $\mathcal{F}_{\lambda}=\{P_{\lambda}(x):\lambda\in\mathbb{R}\}$ satysfying the conditions $$P_{\lambda}(i)=y_i,\;(i=1,2,\ldots 16)\qquad P_{\lambda}(17)=\lambda,$$ where $y_1=0,y_2=0,y_3=1,\ldots,y_{16}=36 $ are the given numbers.

Comment: probably this answer should be updated wrt problem edits.

Comment: @ioann.voronov: Done!

Answer (score 0):

try http://oeis.org/

There you will find two ansers