# 1, 2, 5, 12, 27... What will be the formula to calculate nth term for this sequence.

Tags: sequences-and-series

Here, the difference of the digits at level 2 are in G.P., so is there any generalised formulae for calculating nth term if difference of digits at any level are in G.P.

Comment: See how you obtain each term from the previous. Can you see the pattern?

Comment: OP described the pattern in the question.

Comment: Hint:  go step by step.  You have identified the second difference.  Can you identity the first?  It's just the sum of the second...  Having done that, can you identify the series the same way?

Comment: Are you, as I suspect, looking for a *closed formula* for the `n`th term? - not just a recurrence relation.

Comment: Huh, I'd expected to see a snarky comment, like "19 - it is always 19", by now..

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790642/general-formula-for-the-1-5-19-65-211-sequence

Comment: @Thumbnail Yes for all cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with @Ihf's answer, I think the generalised solution would be that if at any levels difference of terms are in G.P.

$then, n^{th}$  term will be, $$T(n) = \frac{a^{n} + bn + c}{d} $$

where, $a, b, c, d$ are numbers and $n$ is the number of terms.

I, have tested this formula on several cases where difference of terms is in G.P. at any levels, and it is returning me correct answer in all of the cases.

Comment: I think you need a GP plus a polynomial of degree $k-1$ if the GP occurs at level $k$.

Answer (score 4):

The repeated differences are
$$
\begin{array}{}
1 & 2 & 5 & 12 & 27 \\
1 & 3 & 7 & 15 \\
2 & 4 & 8
\end{array}
$$

As you have noticed, the third row is given by $2^n$.

The second row is thus given by the partial sums the third row: $2^n-1$.

The first row is thus given by the partial sums the second row: $2^n-n$.

Comment: Ok. But the 4th row is (2,6,...) and the 5th row is (4,...) .If we assume the 5th row is all 4's we get a 4th-degree polynomial  formula for the first row .