# Find the formula for the sequence $\frac{5}{1},\frac{8}{2},\frac{11}{6},\frac{14}{24},\frac{17}{120}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I'm supposed to find the formula for the sequence:

$$\frac{5}{1},\frac{8}{2},\frac{11}{6},\frac{14}{24},\frac{17}{120}$$

I started by writing this:

$$(\frac{1}{n!})$$

But I don't know how to get the numerator. I know there's a difference of 3 between the numbers, but I don't know how to approach creating a formula for it.

Comment: At lot of times it helps to look at the differences of the successive terms.  Here we see that the difference of successive numerators is always $3$.  That means the desired formula is a linear polynomial with leading coefficient $3$.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1790642/44121. A reasonable form is $\frac{3n+2}{n!}$, but five terms are not enough to distinguish it from $$\frac{67}{120}+\frac{877 n}{96}-\frac{3377 n^2}{576}+\frac{121 n^3}{96}-\frac{263 n^4}{2880}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you see it starts with 5 for $n=1$ and roses by 3 every time. So $5+3(n-1)$ will be the numerator. Simplify everything and put it together with the denominator. $(2+3n)/n!$

Answer (score 1):

Notice the numerator increases by $3$ each time and so the common difference is $d=3$. Now use the formula for the arithmetic sequence $a_n=a+(n-1)d$, where $a$ is the first term and $d$ the common difference. Thus the numerator has the form $5+(n-1)3=2+3n$. And the denominator is as you said $n!$. Thus the sequence is $\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ where
$$a_n=\frac{2+3n}{n!}$$