# Non linear number pattern problem

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need help finding the equation of a pattern on a non linear number sequence.

The sequence is 7, 11, 16, 21.

I understand how to find simple equations when the rule is not changing but this is frustrating me.

Edit: The equation I need is just for this sequence. I don't want to find the numbers after this or before.

Comment: It's clearly $$a_n=n+\lfloor n\cdot r(x)/w(x)\rfloor+\lfloor n\cdot s(x)/w(x)\rfloor+\lfloor n\cdot t(x)/w(x)\rfloor+\lfloor n\cdot u(x)/w(x)\rfloor+\lfloor n\cdot v(x)/w(x)\rfloor$$ with $x=\pi/5$, $ r(x)=\sin x, s(x)=\cos x, t(x)=\tan x, u(x)=\csc x, v(x)=\sec x, w(x)=\cot x$ (https://oeis.org/A190518) ... j/k

Comment: Now really, read this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1790642/general-formula-for-the-1-5-19-65-211-sequence/1790666#1790666

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Math Stack Exchange! Unfortunately there is no way to answer this question without additional information. There are infinitely many possible sequences and no way to know what the next value should be without some way of narrowing the options.